# Are there any wheels or rings that fit in pin clips?

Tags: building, moc, wheel

I was experimenting with Lego part 16091 [Vehicle Steering Wheel Small](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30663) and various clips, mainly the ones that fit onto bars. To my frustration I found that the clips do not engage at all with the ring that forms the wheel’s circumference; they fall right off.

So my question is this: are there any similar parts (wheels, rings) that do engage with clips in this way?

Comment: I feel the following part https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30033#T=S&O={"iconly":0} is relevant here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The small Technic Steering Wheel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2819) and what I think is [this rubber belt](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x1106) connect to clips:

[image: example]